# Codeigniter AJAX search returning error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to make an Ajax search with suggested results as a dropdown, when I type something in I always get the error "Error while request.." and the console displays connection refused to the post url in the view.

Controller:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model('Master_model');
    $search= $this->input->post('search');
    $query = $this->Master_model->getAirportName($search);
    echo json_encode ($query);
    $this->load->view('Master_view'); 
}
```

Model:

```
  function getAirportName($search){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $whereCondition = array('AirportName'=>$search);
    $this->db->where($whereCondition);
    $this->db->from('Airports');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }
```

View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#search").keyup(function(){
        if($("#search").val().length>3){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/flightstats/index.php/Master_controller",
            cache: false,               
            data:'search='+$("#search").val(),
            success: function(response){
                $('#finalResult').html("");
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                if(obj.length>0){
                    try{
                        var items=[];   
                        $.each(obj, function(i,val){                                            
                            items.push($('<li/>').text(val.AirportName + ", " + val.AirportCountry));
                        }); 
                        $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                    }catch(e) {     
                        alert('Exception while request..');
                    }       
                }else{
                    $('#finalResult').html($('<li/>').text("No Data Found"));       
                }       

            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
        });
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>



<div id="container">
<p>Type an airport</p>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
<ul id="finalResult"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for error!!!

Comment: try changing this,`url: "<?= base_url("index.php/Master_controller")"`

Answer (score 0):

In case I understand your issue, you are not suppose to load view for AJAX response. Just `echo json_encode($value)`. However if you put all code - regular view and ajax response in same method, you should check for ajax call with
 `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`, something like:

```
public function index()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        //get data from DB and echo json
    }
    else
    {
        //do initial page load
    }
}
```

Although it is easier to check code if ajax is secluded from initial view code.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your ajax function and controller is one, you should seperate this to two function, one is display form with input and one is return json result.

This is example:

**Controller:** Master_controller.php

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('Master_view'); 
}

public function ajax(){
    $this->load->model('Master_model');
    $search= $this->input->post('search');
    $query = $this->Master_model->getAirportName($search);
    echo json_encode ($query);
}
```

**Model:** Master_model.php

```
public function getAirportName($search){
    $this->db->where('AirportName',$search);
    $this->db->from('Airports');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }
```

**View:** Master_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test ajax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="frmTestAjax">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type some text right here" style="padding: 5px 10px" />
            <ul id="finalResult"></ul>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#search").keyup(function() {
                    if ($("#search").val().length > 3) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "http://localhost/flightstats/index.php/Master_controller/ajax",
                            cache: false,
                            data: 'search=' + $("#search").val(),
                            success: function(response) {
                                $('#finalResult').html("");
                                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                                if (obj.length > 0) {
                                    try {
                                        var items = [];
                                        $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
                                            items.push($('<li/>').text(val.AirportName + ", " + val.AirportCountry));
                                        });
                                        $('#finalResult').append.apply($('#finalResult'), items);
                                    } catch (e) {
                                        alert('Exception while request..');
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $('#finalResult').html($('<li/>').text("No Data Found"));
                                }

                            },
                            error: function() {
                                alert('Error while request..');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

P/s: Sorry, my english is so bad. I'm trying to improve it :)